# When was Software Recommendations instituted?

Tags: discussion

I was trying to figure out if Software Recommendations existed when [this question about game recommendations was asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115135/what-stack-exchange-site-for-game-recommendations/302802#302802) (7 Dec 2011). So, that led me to try to find out when Software Recommendations was founded. I don't see information about it in the help center (and [the about link at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/company/about) just says when Stackoverflow was founded).

Software Recommendations is pretty new to me, but I suppose it could have been around a while.

Comment: about 3-4 years ago. Its a relatively recent site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer can be found by looking up the [corresponding page on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) (where new sites are proposed and getting started). There you can see it was proposed on 2013-10-09 and that its public beta started 2014-02-18.

Answer (score 4):

The first question can be found by writing this URL with identifier "1", because identifiers are incremental:

```
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1
```

... which is [Software to backup Android phone ROM](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1)

It was asked on **February 4 2014 at 19:12** (presumably a few minutes after the private beta started).